# How to copy a string that starts and ends with specific characters in a text file using Java

Tags: java, string, file, search, find

I have copied the page source of a webpage in a text file using Java.

There is this following string in the file and I need to copy only the numbers and save them in an another file.

'numbers', '[670341345,670341248,670320495,670318700,670317434,670315031,670314751,670314299,670311573]');

Simply the string that starts with " 'numbers' , '[ " and ends with " ]'); "

Here is what I did:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class copyID {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    StringBuilder fullPage = new StringBuilder();
    URL olx = new URL (url);

    URLConnection conn = olx.openConnection();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){

        fullPage.append(inputLine+"\n");
}
    in.close();
    saveToFile(fullPage.toString());    }                                                           

    public static void saveToFile(String input){
        try{
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("ID_List.txt"));

            out.write(input);
            out.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e){}

    }



    }
```

How can I do it? I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Why have you shown us that code? It doesn't seem relevant (other than this is how you obtain your data). What have you tried in order to solve this specific problem?

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do it. @duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search string is very specific, so I think even the most hardened anti-regex-HTML folks would be OK with a regular expression here.

The code below shows how you can isolate the text in question and extract the numbers. I assume you can research how to solve the rest of the problem:

```
String example = "sdflkjsdflskdfs0980sdflkjmlsdf'numbers', '[1231231"
    + "23,123123123,1231232,345634,3453534,123123]');asdasdasdasd";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'numbers', '\\[(.*?)\\]'\\);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);

while (matcher.find()) {
  String[] numbers = matcher.group(1).split(",");
  for (String s : numbers) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Output:

```
123123123
123123123
1231232
345634
3453534
123123
```

Comment: Hi @Duncan, I have tried to apply your code to my program but since I couldn't understand the characters in Pattern.compile method, I couldn't have gone further. Can you explain that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `String` methods.

Beware that this only gets what's inside the first occurance of "[..]".

```
String str = "sdflkjsdflskdfs0980sdflkjmlsdf'numbers', '[1231231"
            + "23,123123123,1231232,345634,3453534,123123]');asdasdasdasd";

String subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("[")+1, str.indexOf("]"));

String[] numbers = subStr.split(",");

for(String num: numbers)
   System.out.println(num);
```

Output:

```
123123123
123123123
1231232
345634
3453534
123123
```